# Android - keyboard covering EditText in Arabic / RTL

Tags: android, android-edittext, locale, android-softkeyboard, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a multilingual app in which I want the `EditText` to slide up (with the rest of the screen) when the user clicks on it, i.e. the `EditText` should ***always*** be visible above the keyboard, whenever the keyboard is displayed.

[image]

Obviously this is doable using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`.

Unfortunately, this seems to work properly only when the app language is English. When the user changes the app language to Arabic, the `EditText` slides above the keyboard ***only the first time*** on all OS versions lower than 7.1.1. It works as expected on Android 7.1.1.

[image]

Is this a known issue with Marshmallow 6.0.1 and lower versions? Is there a hack or workaround available to circumvent this?

Comment: this is an issue in pre-N devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix this issue you need to create customEditText and the override
This worked for me.

```
public class CustomEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {

Context context;

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        public static void hideKeyboard(Context context) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS, 0);
}

        clearFocus();
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

then add there two lines to your xml

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

An easy way.you can set edittext gravity to display arabic in RTL like below.either in xml or u can do it dynamically.

In xml do this

```
 <EditText
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:hint="رمز القسيمة الاختياري"
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:textColorHint="#d3d3d3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="14sp"
   />
```

Dynamically u can set like this

```
 textmob.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT); //textmob is object
```

Note: you can do the to your textview element